# slideshow php picture loading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I've been trying to work on an image slideshow website such as http://25000paintings.com
I got the code from a friend and coded for needs but now I come to the problem how to run the image js. Do the pictures need to be converted into php. files and how can I get the script going with around 200 pictures. All the best luk.

Here the js. :

```
var int = setInterval(refresh_painting, 10000);
function refresh_painting()
{
  var p = document.getElementById("painting");
  p.src = "./painting.php" + "?" + Date.parse(new Date());
}
$(window).bind("resize", function(){update_pos();});

function update_pos(){
        var window_width=$(window).width();
        // $(".detail").width = max()
        $(".detail").width(window_width / 2);
        $(".detail").css("left", (window_width) / 4);
        // $(".abstract").css("right", window_width);
        var window_height=$(window).height();
        var detail_height=$(".detail").height();
        var abstract_height=$(".abstract").height();
        $(".detail").css("top", (window_height - detail_height) / 2);
        // $(".abstract").css("top", (window_height - abstract_height) / 2);
    }
function toggle_detail(showOrHide){
    if (showOrHide !== false) {
        showOrHide = 250;
    }
    $('#detail').toggle((showOrHide));
    $('#overlay').toggle(showOrHide);
}
function full_screen(hide){
    p = $('#paintings');
    if (p.hasClass('full_screen') | hide === false){
        p.removeClass('full_screen');
        p.addClass('paintings');
    } else {
        p.addClass('full_screen');
        p.removeClass('paintings');
    }
}
$(document).bind ('keyup.detail', function (k) {
    if (k.keyCode == 27) {
        toggle_detail(false);
        full_screen(false);
    }
});
update_pos();
full_screen();
// $(".abstract").css("position", "absolute");
// toggle_detail();
```

And here the required part in the .html file.

```
</div>
<div id="paintings" class="full_screen">
    <img class="painting" id="painting" src="./painting.php") onclick="javascript:full_screen();" alt="painting">
</div>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./paintings.js"></script>
```

I hope you can help me out!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to convert the images to .php files. The painting.php file in your example would be a script that will send back an image, randomly selected from a pool of images (that `Date.parse(new Date())` part likely acts as the seed for the random number generator in the script).

For a simple rotation of a few images, you could simply add an array containing a bunch of image urls, select one at random in the `refresh_painting()` function, and set `p.src = random image` instead, like so:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
function refresh_painting() {
  var p = document.getElementById("painting");
  var random_image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  p.src = random_image;
}
```